# Unregistered users can ask questions here, but not on StackOverflow. Is this by design?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, user-accounts

Consider this user: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/296/tatsu

He or she asked a suite of pretty bad questions, only one of which (I think) has been retained, presumably  on the grounds that the grounds that my answer to it was worth keeping.

But I have [recently read on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124445/user-merge-request#comment333352_124445) that unregistered users can only answer, not ask. Is this true? If so, why is that not true on Mathematica.SE?

Fortunately we have not had any other cases of bad questions from unregistered users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Users need to register to ask on Stack Overflow [because of the sheer volume of questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107163)